# Printing 2 jpeg files on one side of a paper by CLI

Tags: command-line, printing, lpr

I use debian jessie.
I want to print 2 jpeg files on one side of a paper.

```
$ lpr -o number-up=2 foo1.jpg foo2.jpg
```

This command printed only 1 jpeg file on one side of a paper.
How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this could help you after install imagemagick

and then, try this;

```
 montage foo1.jpg foo2.jpg montage.jpg | lpr -o number-up=2  montage.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mustafa. But as to montage, the above command yields a file of very poor quality. `$ montage -tile 2x1 -geometry 480x640 foo1.jpg foo2.jpg foo_montaged.jpg` is good. And `$ lpr -o number-up=2 montage.jpg` prints just as `$ lpr montage.jpg`